# Finding coordinates on line in 3d environment, given origin and direction

Tags: 3d, coordinate-systems

Working on a 3d game, I've encountered a math problem that gaming/stackoverflow hasn't been able to help with.

Given an origin coordinate x,y,z, and a yaw/pitch direction away, how can I properly calculate the next coordinate (in the right direction)?

Comment: What I understand from your problem is that the origin of the vector is at $(x,y,z)$ and you have two angles a vector makes with respect to some reference axis. If that is the case, the third angle can be anything in the range $(0,2\pi)$ and still match the conditions you have. I mean that every value in that range is valid.

Answer (score 0):

The equation for a line is $l(t) = p_0 + \vec vt$. You have the coordinates of your $p_0$ already, you just need to convert your yaw and pitch values into a single vector $\vec v$.